# JpaRepository method is giving unexpected data

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have this table that hold the following data.

```bash
SELECT * FROM test1;
+---------+------------+-----------+---------+-----------+------------+-----------+
| user_id | has_access | image_url | menu_id | menu_name | service_id | user_name |
+---------+------------+-----------+---------+-----------+------------+-----------+
|      11 |          1 | NULL      |       1 | a         |          1 | aa        |
|      11 |          0 | NULL      |       2 | b         |          1 | aa        |
|      11 |          1 | NULL      |       3 | c         |          1 | aa        |
|      22 |          1 | NULL      |       1 | a         |          1 | bb        |
|      22 |          1 | NULL      |       2 | b         |          1 | bb        |
|      22 |          0 | NULL      |       3 | c         |          1 | bb        |
|      33 |          1 | NULL      |       1 | a         |          1 | cc        |
|      33 |          1 | NULL      |       2 | b         |          1 | cc        |
|      33 |          1 | NULL      |       3 | c         |          1 | cc        |
+---------+------------+-----------+---------+-----------+------------+-----------+
9 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

Entity

```java
@Data
@Entity
@Table(schema = "test1", name = "test1")
public class Test1Table {
    @Id
    private Integer userId;
    @Column
    private Integer serviceId;
    @Column
    private Integer menuId;
    @Column
    private String menuName;
    @Column
    private Boolean hasAccess;
    @Column
    private String userName;
    @Column
    private String imageUrl;
}
```

Jpa File

```java
public interface JpaDaoTest1Table extends JpaRepository<Test1Table, Integer> {
}
```

I have written the following code to see the possible output.

```java
@SpringBootTest
class JpaDaoTest {
    @Autowired
    private JpaDaoTest1Table jpa;

    @Test
    public void context() {
        assertNotNull(jpa);

        var result = jpa.findAll();
        
        System.err.println("----------------------------------");
        for(var k: result) {
            System.err.println(k);
        }
        System.err.println("----------------------------------");
    }

}
```

Unfortunately I am not getting the result I am expecting.
These are the results I am getting when I am executing the test code.

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        smad1_0.user_id,
        smad1_0.has_access,
        smad1_0.image_url,
        smad1_0.menu_id,
        smad1_0.menu_name,
        smad1_0.service_id,
        smad1_0.user_name 
    from
        test1 smad1_0 
----------------------------------
Test1Table (userId=22, serviceId=1, menuId=1, menuName=a, hasAccess=true, userName=bb, imageUrl=null)
Test1Table (userId=33, serviceId=1, menuId=1, menuName=a, hasAccess=true, userName=cc, imageUrl=null)
Test1Table (userId=11, serviceId=1, menuId=1, menuName=a, hasAccess=true, userName=aa, imageUrl=null)
Test1Table (userId=22, serviceId=1, menuId=1, menuName=a, hasAccess=true, userName=bb, imageUrl=null)
Test1Table (userId=33, serviceId=1, menuId=1, menuName=a, hasAccess=true, userName=cc, imageUrl=null)
Test1Table (userId=11, serviceId=1, menuId=1, menuName=a, hasAccess=true, userName=aa, imageUrl=null)
Test1Table (userId=22, serviceId=1, menuId=1, menuName=a, hasAccess=true, userName=bb, imageUrl=null)
Test1Table (userId=33, serviceId=1, menuId=1, menuName=a, hasAccess=true, userName=cc, imageUrl=null)
Test1Table (userId=11, serviceId=1, menuId=1, menuName=a, hasAccess=true, userName=aa, imageUrl=null)
----------------------------------
```

as you can see in the list, menu_id and menu_name is repeating from simple select query. I am guessing this is a bug. I wonder if there is a solution.

If you have any questions please let me know.